# JSF / JBoss Seam how-to: splitting one List<Item> over several ListBoxes (h:selectManyListbox)

Tags: jsf, seam, richfaces, facelets

I'm using these classes:

```
ShoppingCart   <-ManyToMany->   Item   <-ManyToOne->  ItemCategory
```

All of them are JPA `@Entity`s with relevant getters and setters for relations:

#### Shopping cart:

```
public class ShoppingCart {
  ...
  @ManyToMany
  public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
  }
  ...
}
```

#### Item:

```
public class Item {
  ...
  @ManyToOne
  public ItemCategory<Item> getCategory() {
    return category;
  }
  ...
}
```

#### Item category:

```
public class ItemCategory {
  ...
}
```

### The question:

Let's say I have:
Item1, Item2, Item3 in ItemCategory1
Item4, Item5, Item6 in ItemCategory2

I'm trying to build a page where you can choose the shoppingcart.items like this:

```
ItemCategory1: +-----------+
               | Item1     |
               | Item2     |
               | Item3     |  (multi-select with Ctrl)
               +-----------+

ItemCategory2: +-----------+
               | Item4     |
               | Item5     |
               | Item6     |  (multi-select with Ctrl)
               +-----------+
```

How can I do this with JSF/Facelets/Seam ?

Do you have better suggestions for the UI ? (I don't want it to be tree-based or single listbox)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a method where you initialize initialize your object (perhaps `@PostConstruct`), split the values. For example in

```
private Map<ItemCategory<Item>, List<Item>> itemsByCategory;
```

And then iterate with

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.itemsByCategory.entries}" var="entry">
     // show inputs, using entry.key and entry.value
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Somehow the same thing didn't work before, but now it works! Thanks!